# Reconstruct a string from n continuous substrings of fixed length

Tags: string, graph, substring, dynamic-programming, euler-path

I have as input a list of n+2 continuous substrings of length 3.
My goal is to find out whether there exists a string of length n such that all its continuous substrings of length 2 are exactly the input list that I have been given.

How can I efficiently solve this problem (e.g. for strings of length 4000)?

I have tried out a DP approach similiar to the one used for matrix chain multiplication but it didn't work.

Now I am thinking that I could convert this problem into a graph where the substrings are the vertices and two vertices (substrings of length 3) are connected by an edge if the substrings can be joined into a substring of length 4 (e.g. abc and bcd are connected as they can be joined into abcd). Would trying to find a Eulerian path in this graph solve my problem? Or am I completely wrong about all this?

Comment: Did you mean 'contiguous'? Also, if your input list has only length-3 strings, how can a list of substrings of length-2 ever be exactly that input list? Some examples, and more details of what you've tried, would be useful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.